# When handling an HTTP GET request, how can I read the payload?

Tags: node.js, get, hapi.js

When handling an `HTTP GET` request with `hapijs`, how can I read the payload?
Currently, `request.payload` is `null` when handling `GET` requests.
**P.S** - I have no control over how the requests to my web-server are constructed

Comment: Although [the current HTTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) doesn't actually forbid payloads for GET requests, it doesn't require them to work either: "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request." I'm not particularly surprised that libraries don't make such a payload available.

Comment: @IMSoP in general i agree, however, in this particular scenario i have no control over how the requests to my web-server are constructed

Comment: If you are sending payloads you should really be using a POST

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.params` to get url parameter like `/user/:id` -> `request.params.id`. For the query params you can use `request.query` to get query params `/user?id=5` -> `request.query.id`